# Taking a screenshot of a certain URL with Splash

Tags: out-of-memory, screenshot, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to use Scrapy Splash's `render.png` endpoint to take a screenshot of the following URL:

```
https://www.laithwaites.co.uk/product/Kilikanoon-Baroota-Shiraz-2014/66877
```

In practice I make the request with `python-requests`, however, even when I do this in the browser for testing it pushes the cpu usage to over 100% (measured by "top"), hangs for a long time then eventually forces Splash to crash. I guess it's running out of memory.

I've tried increasing `maxrss` from 500 to 1500, but this did not help.  I also tried tweaking the wait/timeout params for the `render.png` endpoint but nothing changed the result.

How can I take a screenshot of this page with Splash?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some issue with JS engine. You can at least get a screenshot if you turn JS off:

```
import requests

script = """
function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  splash.js_enabled = false
  assert(splash:go(url))
  return splash:png()
end
"""

resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8050/execute', json={
    'lua_source': script,
    'url': '<url>',
})
```

If you enable verbose logging (`docker run -it -p8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash -v3`) you can see that Splash hangs after downloading some `fetch.js` file from cloudfront. Probably it contains some code which makes Splash hang. Instead of disabling JS you can try filtering out just this file (abort its download):

```
function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  splash:on_request(function (req) 
    if req.url:find('fetch.js') ~= nil then
      req.abort()
    end
  end)
  assert(splash:go(url))
  return splash:png()
end
```

The script above works for me.